# How to reference an array in a function argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters

I have a series of arrays that contain words I want to use as text in various HTML divs (there are about 35 of these, I included only a few for brevity).

```
var bodyplan = ['Anguilliform', 'Compressiform', 'Depressiform', 'Filiform', 'Fusiform', 'Globiform', 'Sagittiform', 'Taeniform'];

var mouthposition = ["Inferior", "Jawless", "Subterminal", "Superior", "Terminal"];

var barbels = ['1', '2', '4 or more'];

var caudalshape = ['Continuous', 'Emarginate', 'Forked', 'Lunate', 'Rounded', 'Truncate'];
```

I have a switch function that is supposed to change the text based on user selections:

```
switch(n){
            case 1:
            changelabels(bodyplan, 8);
            break;
            case 2:
            changelabels(mouthposition, 5);
            break;
            case 3:
            changelabels(barbels, 3);
            break;
            case 4:
            changelabels(caudalshape, 6);
            break;
            case 5:
            changelabels(dorsalspines, 8);
            break;
            default:
            alert("handquestsel error")}};
```

Finally, I have the function which I would like to make the changes (except it doesn't):

```
function changelabels(opt1,opt2){
    var i = opt2;
    var im = opt2 - 1;
    var c = 1;
    var index = 0;
    while (i>=c){   
        var oldlbl = document.getElementById("rb" + c + "lbl");
        var newlbla = opt1.slice(im,i);
        var newlblb = opt1.toString();
        oldlbl.innerHTML = newlblb; 
        c = c + 1
        index = index + 1
}};
```

I know the code for my function is just plain wrong at this point, but I have altered it so many times that I'm not sure what's going on anymore.  At one point I did have the function able to change the text, but it did so incorrectly (it parsed the name of the array, not extracted a value from the array as I wished).  Please help.  I know I am overlooking some fundamental concepts here, but am not sure which ones.  I've lost count of the hours I've spent trying to figure this out.  It's seems like it should be so simple, yet in all my chaotic attempts to make it work, I have yet to stumble on an answer.

EDIT: I want my switch statement to call the function and pass to the function, the appropriate array from which to pull the labels from.  The purpose of the app is to help a user learn to identify fish.  When the user makes selections on the page, a series of pictures will be shown for various character states with an accompanying label describing the state.  For example, when the user selects *Mouth Position* a series of divs will show the different mouth positions that fish have and have a label below the picture to tell the user what that certain character state is called.  I can get the pictures to change just fine, but I am having a hell of a time with the labels.

Comment: "but I have altered it so many times that I'm not sure what's going on anymore", that's when you get up from your desk, walk around the building 4 times and come back to it.

Comment: What's your end goal?  Making this clearer can help us to determine a better solution.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I have no idea what you're trying to do. Can you elaborate and maybe provide us a bit more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your requirement and code correctly, in your switch statement you are passing both a reference to the appropriate array and that array's expected length - you don't need the second parameter because all JavaScript arrays have a [`.length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

You don't want to use `.slice()` to get the individual values out of the array, because that returns a new array copied out of the original - just use `arrayVariable[index]` to get the individual item at `index`.

So, putting that together try something like this (with your existing array definitions):

```
switch(n){
   case 1:
      changelabels(bodyplan);
      break;
   case 2: 
      changelabels(mouthposition);
   // etc.
}

function changelabels(data) {
   var i,
       lbl;

   for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      lbl = document.getElementById("rb" + (i+1) + "lbl");
      lbl.innerHTML = data[i];
   }
}
```

Notice how much simpler that is than your code? I'm assuming here the elements you are updating have an id in the format "rb1lbl", "rb2lbl", etc, with numbering starting at 1: I'm getting those ids using (i+1) because JavaScript array indexes start at zero. Note also that you don't even need the `lbl` variable: you could just say `document.getElementById("rb" + (i+1) + "lbl").innerHTML = data[i]` - however I've left it in so that we have something to expand on below...

Within your function you seem to be changing the labels on a set of elements (radio button labels?), one per value in the array, but you stop when you run out of array items which means any leftover elements will still hold the values from the previous selection (e.g., if the previous selection was "bodyplan" with 8 options and you change to "mouthposition" with only 5 - you probably should hide the 3 leftover elements that would otherwise continue to display the last few "bodyplan" items. One way to do that is instead of setting your loop up based on the array length you could loop over the elements, and if the current element has an index beyond the end of the array hide it, something like this:

```
function changelabels(data) {
   var i,
       lbl,
       elementCount = 20; // or whatever your element count is

   for (i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
      lbl = document.getElementById("rb" + (i+1) + "lbl");
      if (i < data.length) {
         lbl.innerHTML = data[i];
         lbl.style.display = "";
      } else {
         lbl.innerHTML = "";
         lbl.style.display = "none";
      }
   }
}
```

If these elements are labels for radio buttons (just a guess based on the ids) then you'd also want to hide or show the corresponding radio buttons, but I hope you can figure out how to add a couple of lines to the above to do that.

(As mentioned above, be careful about having element ids count up from 1 when the array indexes start at 0.)

If the above doesn't work please post (at least some of) the relevant HTML - obviously I've just had to guess at what it might be like.

Comment: Thanks to all for responding.  I'm going to try these things today and I'll post the results.  If I can't get it to work, I'm just going to hard-code the changes and move on.

Comment: I took your suggestions. The arrays are still not accessible. I can make the innerHTML statement change the label directly to a string. Ex: 'document.getElementById("rb" + (i+1) + "lbl").innerHTML = "string"'. But if I try to refer to the array '....innerHTML = bodyplan[i]" it doesn't work. For some reason I cannot access the array and I'll be damned if I know why.  I am new to programming, but what I am trying to do isn't very difficult. I had few problems with anything before this and I have pages of code written for this. But this one part where I try to access an array falls flat.

Comment: My suspicions of a problem with scope were confirmed.  I moved the array into the change label function and everything worked just fine.  For some reason the global variables that I declared at the top of the page are not really global.  I have no idea why that is the case though.

Comment: I'm glad it's now working, but really globals are global - there must've been something else going on with your code. You never showed the context for your switch statement, for example, not that that was necessarily it. Still, I hope you at least took on board my suggestions about using the array `.length` property, not using `.slice()` (in this context), and so forth. Your original code was way more complicated than necessary. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just something along the lines of:

```
document.getElementById("bodyplan_label").innerHTML = bodyplan[bodyplan_index];
```

You seem trying to put everything in really abstract data structures, I see no reason to. Just keep it simple.

Also `bodyplan` has only 8 elements, so `bodyplan[8]` will give you an `out of bounds exception` because arrays start at `0` as is common in all modern programming languages.

Comment: I tried this.  The problem seems to be with accessing the arrays.  For instance if I make the statement this: 'document.getElementById("bodyplan_label").innerHTML = "bodyplan[bodyplan_index]";' the labels are changed to the string inside the double quotes.  But when I take away the quotes and try it nothing happens.  The statement works to change the label.  However only if I give it a string to change it to.  I've checked my array declarations to be sure I am using proper syntax, but they just don't seem to be accessible.

Comment: My suspicions of a problem with scope were confirmed. I moved the array into the change label function and everything worked just fine. For some reason the global variables that I declared at the top of the page are not really global. I have no idea why that is the case though.

Comment: `"bodyplan[bodyplan_index]"` means the actual string _bodyplan[bodyplan_index]_, `bodyplan[bodyplan_index]` means the value at position `bodyplan_index` of the array `bodyplan`

Comment: The problem was solved when I moved the array down into the function where it was used instead of having it as a global at the top of the page.  I have no idea why this should be, but apparently using global variables in javascript causes issues.  I never had a problem like this in VisualBasic (the only other language with which I am familiar), but that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Changed the scope of the array variables to local by moving them into the function where they are used, instead of having them as global variables at the top of the page. I don't understand as I was following every rule of variable declaration. But for some unknown reason, global variables in javascript are abhorrent.

Solution Edit: Found an error in declaring my global variables.  This may have been the source of my problem of why I could not access them.  But it is a non-issue at this point since I corrected my code.

Comment: It's good programming practice in any language to keep globals to a minimum, but that's a matter of organisation and modularisation, not a way to avoid an unreliable part of the language. **Globals _do_ work in JavaScript** - there isn't some trick to it. Of course I'm glad you got your program working, but there must have been something else wrong to stop it working as it was. I suspect your "unknown reason" could probably be explained by the more experienced JavaScripters here if we could see all of your code in context - perhaps you could paste it to http://jsbin.com.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what your trying to achieve exactly with your code. But to pass a variable (in this case an array) by reference you just have to add "&" before the variable.

```
function the_name(&$var_by_ref, $var_by_value) {
// Here if you modify $var_by_ref this will change the variable passed to the function.
}
```

More: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Hope that helps.

Comment: In JavaScript arrays are passed by reference always, because it is an object. The pass by reference indicator `&` doesn't exist.